# Increment method returning NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the [increment](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment) method with the following code:

```
object.increment(counter, 1)
```

The code above returns the following error (despite the object having a `counter` attribute):

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `tries' for main:Object
```

Comment: I don't understand the error, but at least it should be `object.increment(:counter, 1)`

Comment: Copy that sentence to an answer and it's a winner.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a symbol for the attribute:

```
object.increment(:counter, 1)
```